# How to change date time format on a localized website?

Tags: xpages, date-format, setlocale

I have a localized website for different languages

Users can select which language to use in a profile and this will be applied beforePageLoad
using

```
context.setLocalString("en")
```

"en" is default to en-US i believe so the dates on the website is displayed in the US format so I learned that I can use instead.

```
context.setLocale(new Locale("en","gb"))
```

the problem with setLocal is that is does not update the HTML lang="en" attribute so event though the dates are correct after using setLocal the language file that is used is still the englisn(US) and not the english(uk) one. (i.e not html lang="en-gb")

so when users from england set their language to en-uk in thier profile they get the US language file.

So I tried to do both like this

```
 context.setLocale(new Locale("en","gb"))
 context.setLocalString("en-GB")
```

but then the setLocalString overrides the setLocalString and vice versa. so it looks like I can't use them both

Is there any way I can add code on beforePageLoad to make sure both the html lang attribute gets updated with correct language and my dates dispay in the correct format for the language set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the *context* object try to set the locale directly in the view root during *beforeRenderResponse*:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
    <![CDATA[#{javascript:
       facesContext.getViewRoot().setLocale( new java.util.Locale("en-GB") );
    }]]>
</xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

Or you can switch the locale in a phase listener as described here:
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=xpages-localization-setter

**EDIT:**

The locale setting is a little bit strange. You have to use an underscore between *en* and *GB* when using *context.setLocaleString()* (as Panu Haaramo answered), but this won't solve problem, because the *ViewRootRender* uses only the language setting for the generation of the *lang* attribute while rendering the HTML output.

This

```
new java.util.Locale("en", "GB").getLanguage()
```

will return *en* only, the "GB" is ignored.

Using the *context.setLocaleString* will bring the same result because this only parses the given string and converts it into a *java.util.Locale* which returns the same result as descibed.

But using an undefined Locale will generate a lowercased *lang* attribute. F.e. this

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:
      facesContext.getViewRoot().setLocale( new java.util.Locale("en-Blabla-Blubb") );
   }]]>
</xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```

generates the following HTML tag:

```
<html lang="en-blabla-blubb">
```

Thats why the code at top of this answer sets the lang attribute to *en-gb*, but this is still incorrect: It should set it to *en-GB* as described here: [w3.org: Best Practices: Specifying Language in XHTML & HTML Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/#ri20030112.213801634)